# Is every continuous CDF the limiting distribution of some sequence of discrete CDFs?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Note: I know that for various measure-theoretic reasons (that I don't fully understand) this does NOT apply to the underlying probability *density*.

I'll accept as answers either a proof, paper to a proof with some explanation (I don't know measure theory beyond the basics), or a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider

$$ F_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \mathbf{1}_{\left( F(x) \geq \frac{k}{n+1} \right) } . $$

You can show that $\left| F_n(x) - F(x) \right| \leq \frac{1}{n}$ .

Can you see which discrete random variable is associated to this CDF?

Comment: Should be correct now :)